# Which Python IDE

Tags: python, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Hi recently started looking at Python, basically for scripting, so far I've been doing exercises from the web, which is OK. I'm using gEdit and its fine. but I'm curious to know what is a good IDE for python, that will still allow me to discover. One of the things I'm used to in Visual Studio is code completion,code snippets and tips, so when you type FOO then CTRL+SPACE you get to see what methods,properties etc are available for FOO. You can select a method press F1 and get HELP on its usage. Really helps discovery and learning. Can anyone recommend a good IDE preferably FREE that works well on windows(Linux is optional) and has features such as code completion,code snippets,code tips

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try Vim or Eclipse.

Comment: This question is the second one on the Python `FAQ` tab.